# DOMPDF solo crea símbolos

Tags: dompdf

Tenía en mi web un botón para generar un pdf usando DOMPDF. He migrado mi web de servidor. He pasado de un sevidor VPS a un hosting con Ionos.
Cuando intengo generar un pdf ahora lo único que me salen son símbolos. He reinstalado la librería y sigue igual.
Os dejo lo que me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Dompdf cuando me genera el pdf salen todos esos símbolos y antes de migrar la web funcionaba.